# How do I bind another key to isearch-forward in EMACS correctly?

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, elisp

I swap between Windows and Linux frequently and constantly press <kbd>C-f</kbd> when I want to search in EMACS. Since I don't need `forward-char` that much, I decided to bind <kbd>C-f</kbd> to `isearch-forward` (default <kbd>C-s</kbd>) instead:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") 'isearch-forward)
```

However, when I search for something and want to search forward again, <kbd>C-f</kbd> doesn't do that, it just starts a new search. <kbd>C-s</kbd> still searches forward again, though.

What would be the correct way to bind <kbd>C-f</kbd> to `isearch-forward`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you're isearching, isearch's own keymap is active, and <kbd>C-s</kbd> is actually calling something different:

```el
(global-set-key (kbd "C-f") 'isearch-forward)
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-f") 'isearch-repeat-forward)
```

You can type <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> whilst isearching to see all the isearch bindings. If you've not done this before, do it -- there are some useful things available which you might never have noticed before.

Comment: Thanks! Regarding C-h b: if you want to learn something new every day, there's clearly enough stuff inside EMACS to last you a lifetime.